# How can I change the background of a website using Bulma?

Tags: css, web, frameworks, bulma

So I am using the CSS framework Bulma.io.
Normally, without it, when doing 
`body {
  background: black;
}`
the background turns black.
But when I use Bulma.io, only the background behind a written text turns black and the rest of the website stays white. So does someone know how I can make the entire website turn black like it normally does without a framework?

Answer (score 6):

Can you provide an example of what you're working with? My snippet below shows how you can change the background color. Other than setting the background-color property, I also set the body height to be the full height of the view.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.5.2/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can apply the [background helper](https://bulma.io/documentation/helpers/color-helpers/#background-color)

```html
<body class="has-background-grey-lighter"></body>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make that by modifying body background color from Generic variables [$body-background-color] override this variable before importing Bulma. an easy

explanation is now available https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/variables/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the background of the whole page, you need to give the html tag a color class.

**example:**

```
 <html lang="en" class="has-background-dark"></html>
```